# timer on web app

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, timer

i want my website(C#) will call async  every 15 min to some c# function 
 how can i do that?

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To me it sounds like the beginning of a slippery slope.

Comment: Do you want the page within the web browser to call back to the server every 15 seconds or do you want a Timer on the server to call an async method every 15 seconds?

Comment: @kfuglsang why would it be a slippery slope, making an ansyncronous Ajax call every 15 seconds to a JSon service using Javascript uses little or no resporces and can be done very easily.

Comment: @kfuglsang i want to run function that update me with some client information and for example there is anew ver for my web site to popup msg and so on...

Comment: Lloyd mybee it is a good solution to call from JS

Comment: In general I am not fond of the idea of having my web servers processing background tasks, instead of serving web requests. Of course, it is always dependent on the application, but I think most cases would benefit of another solutions.

E.g. if the website throws an exception and the IIS pool recycles your background task would be aborted as well. And what happens when you need to scale out - do you want your background tasks processed by all webservers?

Comment: @kfuglsang have you seen the OP's responses to comments, he is looking for a client side async timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a standard [Ajax (utilising client side Javascript) Timer Control](http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/timer-control/) that is part of the [.Net Ajax Framework](http://www.asp.net/ajax) which is included with all versions of ASP.Net 3.5 up, prior to that the Ajax controls were available as a seperate download.

From the MSDN Library [Timer Control Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/bb398865.aspx):

> The Microsoft Ajax  Timer control performs postbacks at defined intervals. If you use the Timer control with an  UpdatePanel control, you can enable partial-page updates at a defined interval. You can also use the Timer control to post the whole page.

Answer (score 13):

You can use a static Timer and start it from the Application_Start() method in Global.asax.

Within Global.asax, add the following field:

```
static Timer _timer = null;
```

Then you can make your Application_Start() like:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_timer == null)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 1000; // some interval
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SomeStaticMethod);
        _timer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth pointing out this is using System.Timers import and not System.Threading

Answer (score 0):

You can use ashx on server side, and client side ajax call.

To to do this on client side 
use setTimeout() and use jquery for ajax call.