# timer lifetime for a IIS web app

Tags: c#, iis, timer

I need to add a retry logic to a web request if a write to db failed. I'd like to try two more times with a delay of 500ms before quitting. There is no requirement to block the user response during retry. My question is, once a response is made, is the timer still alive to complete the retries or is it killed immediately after the response?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8960714/961113

Comment: The retry logic I want is on each user request. Link you sent is for doing something periodically on the web server. It does not explain the question about lifetime of timer.

Comment: if you use a **static** timer, then it would be there until the application domain is recycled by IIS, I am not sure about non-static timer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make use of async/await. It will probably make things a little easier:

```
public SomeResult HandleWebRequest()
{
    StartThing(); //not awaited - fire-and-forget
    //return a response
}
public async void StartThing()
{
    //await Task.Yield(); //return control to call site and finish asynchronously
    for(var numTries = 0; numTries < 3; numTries++)
    {
        if(trySomethingThatMightNotWork)break;
        await Task.Delay(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: The pattern doesn't work for web API. You have to wait for the loop to complete before returning the response.

Comment: @frosty: Um... no you don't. What evidence leads you to say that? WebAPI doesn't come into it. This is a language feature. The method will run synchronously until the first asynchronous yield (`await`) is encountered. This means that the first attempt to `trySomethingThatMightNotWork` will occur before the first `await`. If you want to be fully async, you could add `await Task.Yield()` as the first line of the async method. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.yield%28v=vs.110%29.aspx